# No Crank No Start - Single Click - 2002 Mazda Protege5

Tags: starting, starter, no-crank-no-start, solenoid

2002 Mazda Protege5 will not start. Tried to jump start the car with no success. Confirmed the battery charge and verified all of the fuses are intact. Attached is an MP4 sound file of the clicking sound coming from the engine bay when the ignition is turned to the on position.

[Single click sound from engine bay MP4 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0v2pOHfczrTR3dTUXNNZ2ZqejZMejlqckJFR1dZc1JVeEJn/view?usp=sharing)

Is the next step to replace the starter? Can I source a used one from a junkyard?

Comment: "Can I source a used one from a junkyard?" Might be as bad as the one on your car.

Answer (score 3):

For me the first step would be to connect a booster cable between the engine and the battery earth terminal - to test if any of the grounding cables / straps have failed.

You should then do the same for the supply cable to the starter...

Only then could you consider the starter at fault.